# CW Structure on Self-Homeomorphism Groups

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, topological-groups, cw-complexes

If $X$ is a finite CW complex then according to Milnor's article *On Spaces Having the Homotopy Type of a CW-Complex*, the mapping space

$$Map(X,X)$$

(which we furnish with the compact-open topology) has the homotopy type of a CW complex. Of course Milnor's statement is more general, but this is all I need to know for this.

The composition of maps is continous and makes $Map(X,X)$ into a topological monoid. When we consider the subset of invertible elements

$$Homeo(X)\subseteq Map(X,X)$$

consisting of all the self-homeomorphisms of $X$, the assumptions on $X$ make inversion continuous and $Homeo(X)$ becomes a topological group.

> Is $Homeo(X)$ a subcomplex of $Map(X,X)$? Or more generally does $Homeo(X)$ admit a CW structure (possibly unrelated to that of $Map(X,X)$)?

This should be well-known but I haven't been able to find a reference so I decided to pitch it to you guys. There is enough in the literature covering the infinite-dimensional manifold structure on $Diff(X)$ when $X$ is a compact, smooth manifold, but I haven't been able to dig anything up on the more general homeomorphism groups.

Comment: Does it make sense to talk about subcomplexes if all we know are that they are homotopy equivalent to CW complexes? Is it just some type of relative homotopy you want?

Comment: @ConnorMalin see the second part of the question: I just want to know if it admits a CW structure. If it does, then it seems reasonable to ask if the structures on $Homeo(X)$ and $Map(X,X)$ interact in some way.